# post a gallery with 3 photo on users wall displays only one

Tags: c#, sdk, upload, facebook-opengraph, photo

I have a problem with c# sdk, i try to upload a gallery with 3 photo on my page, the page displays correctly three photo aligned on users wall instead displays only one photo. I don't know why. can someone help me? thanks

more info about this problem i can't solve it

[image that shows the error](http://www.camping.it/erroreopengraph/errore.jpg)

---

Can someone help me? I inserted more details whith an image that describes the problem...
here there is the c# code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> albumParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
albumParameters.Add("message", "camping italy"); 
albumParameters.Add("name", "camping italia");
JsonObject resultAlbum = client.Post("/camping.it/albums", albumParameters) as JsonObject;

string idAlbum = Convert.ToString(resultAlbum["id"]);

foreach (FileInfo foto in new DirectoryInfo("\\server\\gallery\\").GetFiles("*.jpg"))
{
string filepath = foto.FullName;

FacebookMediaObject mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
{
FileName = foto.Name,
ContentType = "image/jpeg"
};

byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
mediaObject.SetValue(fileBytes);

IDictionary<string, object> upload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
upload.Add("@foto.jpg", mediaObject);
upload.Add("message", "camping italy");
JsonObject resultFoto = client.Post("/" + idAlbum + "/photos", upload) as JsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’re doing a separate post for each photo?

Facebook does not display posts made shortly after another if they all have the same message – only the first of these will be shown on the user’s wall.

Comment: i try to upload photos with different text and in different time after 1 minute but facebook always shows 1 photo (last upload) in the home of the user